# Why won't my villagers breed in Vanilla Minecraft 1.15.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing on a 1.15.2 Vanilla Minecraft server that I started in order to play with my friends. I have created a villager enclosure, but the 5 villagers that I have won't breed to fill my 8 beds. I also have plenty of workstations, and I have given them *plenty* of carrots (Like a stack each). If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've been having the exact same problem in my 1.17 world

Answer (score -1):

Try running the command `/gamerule mobGriefing true`, otherwise I don't know whats happening.

Comment: They pick up plenty of food, they just don't appear to want to breed. This is just survival with no changed gamerules. Idk either. :/

Answer (score -1):

You could try feeding them other foods that they will eat.

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Villager_farming#Mechanics), you can feed them Bread, Carrots, Potatoes, and Beetroots. Bread gives 3 food points while Carrots, Potatoes and Beetroots give 1 food point. Your best bet would be to feed them bread.

> Any mix of the items mentioned can be used as long as they total at least 12 points.